# Downloading images in background on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing an app in which I am downloading images from a webservice. If there are multiple images then it consumes a lot of time. So I want to download multiple images using a thread in background and display them on Image Control as they get downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer  setting BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation make a work in background.It was so easy

```
BitmapImage imgage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(b, UriKind.Absolute));
            imgage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
```

If you want more Information then follow
[MSDN POST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Background file transfer for windows phone that helps you to download/upload files in background you read more about background file transfer from [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202959%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Background file transfer does not guarantees that download will be started immediately and also will continue downloading when the application will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Background worker class. Take a look into official documentation - [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).